# Reading values over ssh in python

Tags: python

I would like to be able to gather the values for number of CPUs on a server and stuff like storage space etc and assign them to local variables in a python script. I have paramiko set up, so I can SSH to remote Linux nodes and run arbitrary commands on them, and then have the output returned to the script. However, many commands are very verbose "such as df -h", when all I want to assign is a single integer or value.

For the case of number of CPUs, there is Python functionality such as through the psutil module to get this value. Such as 'psutil.NUM_CPUS' which returns an integer. However, while I can run this locally, I can't exactly execute it on remote nodes as they don't have the python environment configured.

I am wondering how common it is to manually parse output of linux commands (such as df -h etc) and then grab an integer from it (similar to how bash has a "cut" function). Or whether it is somehow better to set up an environment on each remote server (or a better way).

Comment: Just run a chain of commands remotely that returns the value and don't sweat it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is very common to manually parse output of linux commands, but you shouln't. This is a really common server admin task and you shouldn't re invent the wheel.

You can use something like sar to log remote stats and retrieve the reports over ssh. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-perfmonsar.html

You should also look at salt. It lets you run the same command on multiple machines and get their output.
http://www.saltstack.com/

These are some of the options but remember to keep it DRY ;)

Comment: I'm not so sure if sar is the best tool here? Looks like it has to be active and configured to be collecting data before you can actually query it.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Floris, I believe the simplest way is to design your commands so that the result is simple to parse. However, parsing the result of one command is not at all uncommon, bash scripts are full of `grep`, `sed`, `wc` or `awk` commands that do exactly that.

The same approach is used by psutils itself, [see how it reads `/proc/cpuinfo` for `cpu_count`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/_pslinux.py#256). You can implement the same parsing, only reading the distant `/proc/cpuinfo`, or counting the lines in the output of `ls -1 /sys/bus/cpu/devices/`.

Actually, the best way to get information will be from `/proc` and `/sys`, they are specially designed to ease access to internal information from simple programs, with minimal parsing needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your own programs or scripts on the remote machine there are a couple of things you can do:

1. Write a script on the remote machine that outputs just what you want, and execute that over ssh.
2. Use ssh to tunnel a port on the other machine and communicate with a server on the remote machine which will respond to requests for information with the data you want over a socket.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an SSH connection I would suggest to wrap your commands with
Python's [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) library. It's really nice for this kind of task and you get results really fast.

```
from sh import ssh

myserver = ssh.bake("myserver.com", p=1393)

print(myserver) # "/usr/bin/ssh myserver.com -p 1393"

# resolves to "/usr/bin/ssh myserver.com -p 1393 whoami"
iam2 = myserver.whoami()
```